# Modify a linux file, and save in Python

Tags: python, linux

My goal is to modify a linux config file and update one of the settings from :

PasswordAuthentication `no` --> PasswordAuthentication `yes`

---

I have

```
import os
import fileinput


username = raw_input("Enter username : ")
os.system("adduser -m "+username )
os.system("echo {PASSWORD-HERE} | passwd" + username)
os.system("usermod -aG sudo "+username )
os.system("chsh -s /bin/bash "+username )

with fileinput.FileInput('/etc/ssh/sshd_config', inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line.replace('PasswordAuthentication yes', 'PasswordAuthentication no'), end='')

os.system("service ssh restart ")
```

---

Am I on the right track ?

Comment: Just example from life... 

`What happens when there is missing "PasswordAuthentication no"
What happens when there is "passwordauthentication yes"
What will happen if there is a typo "PasswordAuthentication no."
What if there is already "PasswordAuthentication yes"
What if the whole file is missing ?
You also can't place the "PasswordAuthentication yes" at the bottom of the config file...`

Comment: Nice comment  ✨

Comment: You cocvered most of the points I didn't think about. You're totally correct

Answer (score 0):

str.replace will take first argument as "old string" and second one as "New string"

```
str.replace(old, new[, max])
```

you have given it in reverse.